# Activate two menu items

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I am using Drupal 6. How would I programmatically activate two or more menu items when I am on a certain node page?

Answer (score 1):

Use [menu_set_active_item](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_item/6)

Comment: Works perfectly when you need to activate 1 menu item. But it seems impossible to activate 2 menu items at the same time with that function.

Comment: Right... I see only Javascript to do this but maybe somebody have another idea.